# Can't set object for NSCache

Tags: swift, firebase, caching

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't work. I am trying to get get a cache to store my user images from Firebase so I can store them on the users' phone. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {

func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {
                let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString)
                            
                            self.image = downloadedImage
                        }
                    }
                    
                    }).resume()
      }

}
```

I keep getting the error: Cannot invoke 'setObject' with an argument list of type '(UIImage, forKey: String)'

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: create image cache like this `let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()` instead of `NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the argument list for `NSCache`. Also, fixed the image loading from cache if available logic. Here's the code:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {
        if let image = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = image
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```