# Swift - NSCache doesn't want to save image

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement my own image caching, and I'm stuck.
`NSCache` just doesn't want to save image if `setObject` is called from the `URLSession` task. So it's re-downloading the image every single time.

```
class CustomUIImageView: UIImageView {
    
    static let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func downloadImage(from url: URL, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.image = placeholder }
        
        let cacheKey = NSString(string: url.absoluteString)
        
        if let image = Self.cache.object(forKey: cacheKey) {
            print("cached image")
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.image = image }
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let self = self,
                  error == nil,
                  let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200,
                  let data = data,
                  let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
            
            
            Self.cache.setObject(image, forKey: cacheKey)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.image = image }
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong for about 4 hours now. Every code snippet that I found(to compare) is similar to mine. For example [Can't set object for NSCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581235/cant-set-object-for-nscache)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I also tried creating it in viewcontroller and passing in downloadImage, didn't help. :|

Comment: Likely that lifetime is also too short. Caches, almost by definiton, should live as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomUIImageView: UIImageView {
    
    let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    /// ....
}
```

This creates a new instance of NSCache for each `CustomUIImageView` - you probably want to make the cache `static`, like so:

```
class CustomUIImageView: UIImageView {
    
    private static let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    /// ....
}
```

You will need to change `self.cache` to `Self.cache`, but that should to the trick.

Comment: Just tried your solution. Didn't help. It just never hits `print("cached image")`

Comment: Add logging for your `cacheKey`, both when storing and retrieving in/from the cache. Are the URLs really identical each time?

Comment: Yes, 

`Retrieving key: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603993097397-89c963e325c7`
`Storing key: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603993097397-89c963e325c7`

It only doesn't work in the completion block, if I move `setObject` before `URLSession`. And try to save empty `UIImage()`, It works :|

Comment: Not sure what the hell was that, but I quit xcode, restarted my mac, and it started working, even the non-static one...